# Read File to String in Java Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, file-upload, file-io

I have a form in  my HTML page where users fill out two text fields or upload two files, and click a single button to submit. Here is the code for the form:

```
<form name="submitButton" action="DAOserv" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="SQL_form">
                    <div >
                        <textarea name="SQL" placeholder="BAU Reason"
                            rows="11"></textarea>
                        <label for="BAUInputFile">BAU File</label> <input type="file"
                            id="BAUInputFile">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div >
                    <div >
                        <textarea name="BAU" placeholder="SQL Queries"
                            rows="11"></textarea>
                        <label for="SQLInputFile">SQL File</label> <input type="file"
                            id="SQLInputFile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
```

To clarify, the first DIV contains the text box and file upload button for a set of Queries, and the second contains a text box and file upload button  for a business reason. The user must either upload a file or write into each of the two sections.

The button click submits both of the form fields, but what I can't figure out or find a solution to online (most post talk about uploading the file to the servlet directory) is how to simply read the files to a string, **when the user has uploaded a file to one or both of the two form fields**.

In essence, the servlet will check each text field, if it is null, it will check to see if there is a file that has been uploaded, and if so, it will parse the text in that file to a string.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Essentially you don't really want to upload a file. You want to read the file in javascript and put its contents in the box, then submit a regular form that's not `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Servlet3.0

Look at this thread [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

You'll get filepart content something like this

```
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
```

To read file content to String

1. through Apache IOUtils

   String text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
2. Java Stream reading

   StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
         (inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
           int c = 0;
           while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
               textBuilder.append((char) c);
           }
       }
3. Reading with Java8

   public static String read(InputStream input) throws IOException {
           try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))) {
               return buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
           }
       }

Hope this helps!